# Is there any way to access the git repository when pushing to openshift (v2)?

Tags: openshift

I'd like to access the git commit hash and tag, say using `git describe`, but the openshift virtual machines seem to have no git repository (readable by me anyway).

Is there any way to access this information using the openshift deployment hooks? I'd like to be able to have each instance log the version (ie tag/commit hash) it's running.

At the moment, my best option seems to be to write a deployment script, and use `rhc scp` to push the version string to the server, but it feels a bit hacky.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you found a solution? If not, can you post your deployment script...

Comment: unfortunately not :(.